# How to get element form response.data

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an element from response.data.

here's my code:

```
catch (err){
   

    let errr=err.response.data; 
  // let g=data.document.querySelector('.error__msg');
    console.log(errr);
    
    showAlert('error',errr);  
  }
```

and the output of console.log(errr);

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/img/favicon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,700">
        <title>Natours | Something went wrong!</title></head><body><!-- HEADER--><header class="header">
            <nav class="nav nav--tours"><a class="nav__el" href="/">All tours</a></nav><div class="header__logo">
                <img src="/img/logo-white.png" alt="Natours logo"></div><nav class="nav nav--user"><form class="form form--logout">
                    <button class="btn btn--green">logout</button></form><a class="nav__el" href="/me"><img class="nav__user-img" src="/img/users/user-1.jpg" alt="Photo of athar">
                        <span>athar</span></a></nav></header>
                        <!-- CONTENT--><main class="main"><div class="error"><div class="error__title"><h2 class="heading-secondary heading-secondary--error">Uh oh! Something went wrong!   </h2><h2 class="error__emoji"> </h2></div><div class="error__msg">Validation failed: email: Please provide a valid email</div></div></main>
                        <!-- FOOTER--><footer class="footer"><div class="footer__logo"><img src="/img/logo-green.png" alt="Natour logo"></div><ul class="footer__nav"><li><a href="#">About us</a></li><li><a href="#">Download apps</a></li><li>
                            <a href="#">Become a guide</a></li><li><a href="#">Careers</a></li><li><a href="#">Contact</a></li></ul><p class="footer__copyright">&copy; by Jonas Schmedtmann. Feel free to use this project for your own purposes, EXCEPT producing your own course or tutorials!</p></footer><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.x-git.js"></script><script src="/js/bundle.js">  
                                     </script></body></html>
```

I need to get this message (Validation failed: email: Please provide a valid email) from the HTML response.

thanks...

Comment: sorry, I have updated it to javascript.

Comment: I'm trying to get a response from another form and using  `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: so, I did use response.data with axios when I'm handling the errors to get back the rendered page with the error but I just want to show the error as a popup window not to go to the error page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of your use case but if you want to solve it anyway you can do something like this.

```
catch(err) {
  let errr=err.response.data; 
  // let g=data.document.querySelector('.error__msg');
  const htmlFile = new DOMParser().parseFromString(errr, 'text/html');

  const errorMessage = htmlFile.getElementsByClassName('error__msg')[0].innerText;

  console.log(errorMessage)

  showAlert('error', errorMessage);  
}
```